# Какой content_type у GIF?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Как мне детектить гиф в тг?
В документации есть список `content_type` , но тут нет гиф:
`text, audio, document, photo, sticker, video, video_note, voice, location, contact, new_chat_members, left_chat_member, new_chat_title, new_chat_photo, delete_chat_photo, group_chat_created, supergroup_chat_created, channel_chat_created, migrate_to_chat_id, migrate_from_chat_id, pinned_message, web_app_data.`

Comment: Думаю, photo или document

Comment: у меня стоит и фото и документ, но гиф не определяется

Answer (score 2):

у GIF `content_type` = `animation`